# Ionic cordova | How to create a compass which bearing / heading to a specific location

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

Ionic cordova | How to create a compass which bearing / heading to a specific location (for example, store or restaurant).

I couldn't find any solution and I'm not sure if this could be done with angular TypeScript or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This is of course possible to implement:

```
tanθ = sinΔλ⋅cosφ2 / cosφ1⋅sinφ2 − sinφ1⋅cosφ2⋅cosΔλ
```

See [mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55417.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20171219235009/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55417.html) for derivation

The easiest way is to use an existing library such as [geodesy](https://github.com/chrisveness/geodesy) which implements this as [`initialBearingTo()`](https://github.com/chrisveness/geodesy/blob/master/latlon-spherical.js#L220)

Comment: is it gonna use the device orientation sensor? and how? then how to inmate as a real compass, thanks for your effort.

Comment: [cordova-plugin-device-orientation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-orientation) or [W3C Device Orientation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation)